# HTTP website returns 403.4 even when using Plesk Permanent SEO-safe 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: 301-redirect, https, iis, plesk

My domain has a valid and activated *"Let's Encrypt!"* certificate, and going to `https://example.com` works as it should and shows as being secure in the browser.

Through **Plesk Onyx 17.5.3** I have activated the option **Permanent SEO-safe 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS** in **Hosting Settings**.

But when going to `http://example.com`, it shows a 403.4 Forbidden error and that I should use the https version of the website instead of redirecting to it.

Answer (score 3):

In **IIS Settings** the option **Require SSL/TLS** must be turned **off**.

- With it turned on, HTTP will always return a 403.4 Forbidden error.
- With it turned off, the **Permanent SEO-safe 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS** option works, automatically rewriting the http address into a https address.